# How to create a folder in a folder by PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a folder in an existing folder, I am now using this code but it doesn't work....

```
<?php
    mkdir($_GET['coursename']. "/" .$_GET['name'],0777);
    header("Location:index.php?coursename=".$_GET['coursename']);
?>
```

When I use `<?php mkdir($_GET['name'],0777); ?>` it works normally...
 Please I need Help for make me able to do that...!

Comment: I would say the path is incorrect... Try printing out both (`print_r($_GET)`) and navigate to the output directly to check if it's a correct path. And realize that it is **extremely insecure** to do file operations with unsanitized user input. Like, really.

Comment: thank you ...... the path is correct and it isn't work...... I try and try

Answer (score 3):

Did you notice the third param to `mkdir()`

> recursive Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the
>   pathname.

So try:

```
mkdir($_GET['coursename']."/".$_GET['name'],0777, true);
```

Comment: thank you.... it isn't working .... the problem i have, the code creates the folder but not in exist folder.......